Why can't I choose from more SE sites?
This question just popped up, and I thought it belonged on another site in the SE environment, as it is more about programming an application, instead of bitcoin. I wanted to flag it, but I could just choose the Meta site, instead of something else. Am I doing something wrong? I added two screenshots, one from the attempted flag, and one of the question, in case it gets deleted or rigorously edited.



There are 123 sites on the network (currently), which ones, in the 5 available slots (4, since meta is one) do you think are good candidates and why?

I didn't knew there were limited slots. I would like to nominate StackOverflow because some questions are more about programming, then bitcoin itself. I think the linked question is an example of this. Some others are this one and this one. I'm not sure where we should draw the line between bitcoin.SE and SO, but I think that SO has the highest chance to be a better site for some questions

Also there are quite a lot of questions (some of mine) which ask about error codes while compiling or executing a bitcoin program (not specifically miners). Those could be better sometimes on SuperUser.SE (I don't use that one much, so I don't know exactly if that is right)

The process for adding to migration slots involved the site moderators and Stack Exchange community managers - we require that the site shows a significant amount of migrations to a site and that a good percentage of these migrations end well (i.e. not closed on the other end). This is information that is available to the moderators.

Up to this day, we've had only ten migrations away from Bitcoin.SE. Six were to our own Meta, two to Cryptography, one to Databases, and one to Unix&Linux. I don't think we qualify for "significant amount". ;)

That aren't significant numbers indeed. I will flag it with other (needs ♦ moderator attention) if something like this happens again

I think the UI and limited slots is a deficiency of stack exchange (that has probably been discussed elsewhere). The current UI flow is bad when someone wants to indicate something should be moved to a non-listed site. The sane thing to do would be for SE to change the migration UI to have the list and an "Other" entry (that it could turn into a regular "flag for moderator attention" if that's all they want to implement).

To summarize all the comments on the question: There are only a five slots available to set Migration Target Sites.
None of them currently are set, as we haven't had a significant number of Migrations yet.
If you feel something should be migrated, please just flag other (needs ♦ moderator attention) and explain your proposition.
